# Why won't Objective C classes autocomplete in swift? (updated)

Tags: ios, swift

I am importing my Objective C classes in a bridging header file into Swift:

Bridging Header

```
#import "MyCustomClass.h"
```

In my swift class, I am trying to use this code:

```
var x = MyCustomClass()
x.myFunMethod()
```

However, before I run/build I get "Use of unresolved identifier" errors at the above two lines. Furthermore, I cannot use autocomplete to type out `x.myFunMethod()`. Once I run/build, the errors go away and the app runs as normal.

Comment: Xcode bug. Report using bugreport.apple.com